# Comparing chars within Java StringBuffer

Tags: java, string, char, compare, stringbuffer

I want to check if the char at a certain index in a StringBuffer is equal to a char. I am getting an error, how do I compare them? Here's my code:

```
//I have an established StringBuffer called stringbuffer

char[] mychar = null;
for(int i = 0; i < stringbuffer.length(); ++i){
        if(stringbuffer.charAt(i) != " "){
              mychar[i] = stringbuffer.charAt(i);
        }
}
```

The error I am getting is incompatible operand types char and String. Not sure why, because I am comparing a char of a StringBuffer, not a String or StringBuffer.

Comment: You're comparing a char with a String literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values of `char` type are surrounded with `'`, Strings are surrounded with `"` and you can't compare `char` with `String` with `==` in Java.

Try with

```
if(stringbuffer.charAt(i) != ' '){
```

or maybe cleaner (but this will check fore more than just simple `' '`)

```
if (! Character.isWhitespace(stringbuffer.charAt(i)) ) {
```